# Gravity battery output calculation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy, electricity, batteries

Let’s assume I lift a 1 ton weight to 20feet high.

To calculate the amount of potential energy stored in a 1-ton weight (2000 pounds) lifted to a height of 20 feet,

Potential Energy (PE) = mass × acceleration due to gravity × height

1 ton = 2000 pounds = 2000 lbs
Height = 20 feet

1 pound = 0.453592 kilograms
1 foot = 0.3048 meters

Mass = 2000 lbs × 0.453592 kg/lb ≈ 907.185 kg
Height = 20 feet × 0.3048 m/foot ≈ 6.096 m

$PE = 907.185 kg × 9.81 m/s² × 6.096 m ≈ 53,226.89 joules$

approximately 53,226.89 joules of potential energy are stored in a 1-ton weight lifted to a height of 20 feet.

If I directly convert joules to kWh :

$1 joule = 2.7778 x 10^{-7} kilowatt-hours (kWh)$

$53,226.89 joules * (2.7778 x 10^{-7} kWh/joule) ≈ 0.0148 kWh$

So, 53,226.89 joules is approximately equal to 0.0148 kWh. does this mean this system can only produce 0.0148 kw in one hour? Or am I missing something here as it appears significantly too low output compared to energy required to lift the weight.

Comment: I won't bother with checking your numbers, but it wouldn't be surprising if your calculation is right. Potential energy stored in the gravity of earth has a very small energy per mass ratio.

Comment: BTW, Google Calculator can do stuff like this [`(2000 lb) * (20 feet) * (9.80665 m/s^2) in kwh`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%282000+lb%29+*+%2820+feet%29+*+%289.80665+m%2Fs%5E2%29+in+kwh)

Answer (score 1):

> does this mean this system can only produce 0.0148 kw in one hour?

Your units are wrong with this statement. kWh is a kilowatt (1000 watts) *times* an hour, that is a kilowatt *for* an hour. So this system can produce 0.0148 kW for one hour. It can produce a different amount of power for a different amount of time, as long as the product of power and time is still the same as 0.0148 kWh. Energy is conserved, not power.

Note that a kWh is 1000W * 3600s = 3.6 MJ. That is "megajoules" as in 3.6 million joules. So that tells you how small a Joule is in terms of ordinary energy usage.

Answer (score 0):

> does this mean this system can only produce 0.0148 kw in one hour?

It can produce that much power for an entire hour.   It can produce more power for a shorter period of time.

> it appears significantly too low output compared to energy required to lift the weight.

Imagine a car lift.  If you hook up a small engine (say around 2kW), how long would you expect it to take to lift a car overhead?  Should be able to do that in around a minute.   In other words, this task is a small fraction of a kWh, which is pretty close to your figure.

Comment: What I don't get is if it's connected to an alternator which has more gears, it will require more torque similar to a wind turbine. I'm not sure how to quantify the work done in alternator assuming there is a highly efficient gear system like wind turbine.  With high torque requirement, weight must be falling extremely slow producing output on every bit of displacement by pull of gravity. Of course law of conservation of energy should hold, but equating P.E due to gravity == K.E due to gears seems to miss the mechanical advantage.

Comment: With higher torque the weight falls more slowly, so the power during the fall is less.   Instantaneous power is torque times rotational velocity.

Comment: @Shanthakumar, a gear system does not change the total energy (assuming no losses, all real gears will have losses). All the gears do is exchange torque for rotation or visa versa. It can change the instantaneous power and the time of operation.